GHZ Definition - Does it all have to be $|000\ldots\rangle$ or $|111\ldots\rangle$ or can it be $|010\ldots\rangle$ or $|101\ldots\rangle$
Trying to dig a bit into GHZ States and the proper definition.
Trying to determine if GHZ state is strictly $|000\ldots\rangle$ or $|111\ldots\rangle$ or can it be $|010\ldots\rangle$ or $|101\ldots\rangle$. This is with the consideration that the qubits are entangled.

Or if something like the following still applies:

On the basis of:

and 
From Bell’s theorem without inequalities, Page 9.
Thank you so much for your time!

Please don't use images for text or mathematical formulas as they don't render correctly in many situations (e.g. their size is unrelated to the font size making them potentially unintelligible). Please use latex instead.

See also here

Thank you for the edits, was trying to get Latex to work for 5+ minutes and it was not working. Checking again to see how it's done.

Thanks Mark for that link, checking it and reading the associated paper. Not sure if what I'm looking for is a W state instead?

This should help. You can also click on "Edit", "Improve this question" or "Improve this answer" on any post to see how the author wrote their formulas in tex/mathjax.

TL;DR: No, these are not GHZ states. They are cat states.
GHZ state
The GHZ state is defined as the state
\begin{equation}
\frac{|000\rangle+|111\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}.\tag1
\end{equation}
Generalized GHZ state
More generally, the $n$-qubit state
\begin{equation}
\frac{|0^{\otimes n}\rangle+|1^{\otimes n}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\tag2
\end{equation}
is referred to as the generalized GHZ state. In both cases all qubits have equal labels.
That said, note that the label assignment to computational basis states (and indeed to any basis states) is a matter of convention. Still, for any choice of computational basis on $n$ qubits there exists a single GHZ state.
Cat states
A more general class of states, which includes the states where different qubits have potentially unequal labels, are the cat states. These are states of the form
\begin{equation}
\frac{|b\rangle+|\overline{b}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\tag3
\end{equation}
where $b\in\{0,1\}^n$ is a string of $n$ bits and $\overline{b}$ is the bit string obtained by flipping every bit in $b$.
In some areas, e.g. quantum optics, this term is used even more generally  to refer to any state of the form $(|\psi\rangle+|\phi\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ where $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ have small, but non-zero overlap $\langle\psi|\phi\rangle$. In such contexts, people often refer to the state with $\langle\psi|\phi\rangle=0$ as the "ideal cat state".

Thank you! Follow up questions: What would you call a section where three qubit's that are entangled in a quantum circuit? Is that a GHZ subcircuit? Is that just proven that it works because of the existence of the GHZ state? Thank you once again for your help!

For example, are there 3 GHZ state subcircuits in the following comments. OPENQASM and QISKIT (They're the same thing, just wanted to include both in case one is easier to use). Note QISKIT required two comments

OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q[3];
creg c[2];
reset q[0];
reset q[1];
reset q[2];
h q[0];
cx q[0], q[1];
cx q[0], q[2];
h q[0];
h q[1];
h q[2];
x q[0];
x q[1];
x q[2];
h q[0];
h q[1];
h q[2];
cx q[0], q[1];
cx q[0], q[2];
ccx q[2], q[1], q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
measure q[1] -> c[1];
measure q[2] -> c[1];
// @columns [0,0,0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

circuit.reset(qreg_q[0])
circuit.reset(qreg_q[1])
circuit.reset(qreg_q[2])
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.cx(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[1])
circuit.cx(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[2])
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])

circuit.h(qreg_q[1])
circuit.h(qreg_q[2])
circuit.x(qreg_q[0])
circuit.x(qreg_q[1])
circuit.x(qreg_q[2])
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.h(qreg_q[1])
circuit.h(qreg_q[2])
circuit.cx(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[1])
circuit.cx(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[2])
circuit.ccx(qreg_q[2], qreg_q[1], qreg_q[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[1], creg_c[1])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[2], creg_c[1])
@columns [0,0,0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

Comments are meant for, well, comments, not for follow-up questions (which should be posted as new questions to attract wider attention). In any case, "GHZ subcircuit" sounds good. "GHZ preparation circuit" would also be fine.

Thank you very much!

The general definition of a GHZ state, defined for $n$ qubits (this definition can be extended to qudits too) is
$$|\text{GHZ}_n\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |0\rangle^{\otimes n} + |1\rangle^{\otimes n} \right).$$
Clearly, the 3 qubit GHZ state is then defined as:
$$| \text{GHZ} \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle + |111\rangle).$$
While the other states you mentioned are maximally entangled and exhibit extreme non-classical properties, they do not fit the standard GHZ definition.

It is a matter of convention as to how one defines the term "GHZ state". However, if one wants to study entanglement as a resource, then one imagines the following scenario. Each qubit is with a different party, and each party can each apply local unitary transformations (or some other class of single-qubit operations) to their particular qubit freely. Two multi-qubit state are considered equivalent from the point of view of entanglement theory if they can be transformed into one another using such local unitary transformations. (Of course, the notion of equivalence depends on what operations you allow. Sometimes one further restricts to local Clifford unitaries.)
The state you wrote down seems to be obtainable from a GHZ state via local unitary transformations, so I would say it is equivalent to a GHZ state.

Thank you, this was extremely helpful! Led me to:
https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25821/how-to-prove-that-there-are-only-two-entanglement-classes-of-3-qubit-states#:~:text=One%20set%20contains%20the%20W,maximally%20entangled%20in%20different%20senses.
Which had
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.00862
Which has some really helpful sections, especially on page 4
